# definig a route to a LAN ip

Tags: networking, routing, sonicwall, odoo

**I'm very puzzled by the following situation:**

A new system is currently being installed **on our LAN** (Openerp v8 - Odoo) 
and for some reasons the contractor is asking me to " *add a host name in my router* " 
to be able to access the url of the erp (symbolic name) rather than directly its local ip address, arguing that ip won't work consistently with Odoo v8.

In short making any LAN request for "*odoo.mydomain.tld*" to be routed to LAN 192.168.1.150

By default such kind of request are going outside to the Internet and are resolved by the defaut DNS of our Internet access Provider.

I don't have any internal DNS.
We use a sonicwall appliance (router/firewall) attached to an adsl modem.

So, I have no idea how I can acheive this...

Thank you

Comment: It sounds as though your contractor believes that your router acts as a DNS proxy. I'd recommend getting a better contractor...

Comment: well..no so easy ..

Comment: Sure it is: "you're incompetent and we will no longer be engaging your services.  Please bugger off."

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prevent you from setting a private (RFC1918) IP address in a public DNS server.

So you can create a A record you are asked for in the public DNS, your internal clients will be able to resolve it and connect to the openerp instance.

(Some -paranoid- people may see this as a disclosure of the IP address of an internal server but there's actually no real risk).

Comment: I'll check this, but the windows host file edition looks easier (because we are very small)